# Combining stdin prompt with the output from sub process

Tags: go, subprocess

Suppose I have a program that simply takes an input and do some processing with it.
Like this

**myprog.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i int
    fmt.Print("Type a number: ")
    fmt.Scan(&i)
    fmt.Println("Incremented:", i+1)
}
```

Now I compile this and call this program as a sub process like this

**testsub.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    subProcess := exec.Command("./myprog")

    go func() {
        stdin, err := subProcess.StdinPipe()
        defer stdin.Close()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        io.WriteString(stdin, "33")

    }()
    output, err := subProcess.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(output))
}
```

The output I'm getting is

```
Type a number: Incremented: 34
```

The prompt I wrote into stdin is not displayed. I'm assuming this is because only the output is written to sub process's stdout and not the prompt we wrote to stdin. Is it possible to get following output without making hacky work arounds like modifying the output text or so.?

```
Type a number: 33
Incremented: 34
```

Comment: You don't see `33` because it is never written to any output. The string is directly sent to the stdin of the child process. That's what a pipe is.

Comment: @BurakSerdar yes, is there any way we could achieve the same output as what an user sees when they do the prompt.

Comment: You have to do what a user does: Parse the output of the child process, see when the prompt is printed, send the input first to stdout and then to the child process, and then read the input again.

Comment: Sadly it's not possible in my original use case, basically I'm calling a code executor of a certain language, the prompts will be "dynamic" based on the program user written so i can't really parse the output and modify it.